# PHP | Como muestro elementos de un directorio y ordeno aleatoriamente?

Tags: php

estoy tratando de hacer una lista de músicas, tengo todas las músicas en una carpeta y quiero que cada vez que se refresque la pantalla me desordene, ya logre llamar a todas las músicas de la carpeta con `dir()`, pero lo que no me sale es que cada vez que se refresque la pantalla me desordene la carpeta, tengo entendido que se hace con `shuffle()`, pero no me esta funcionando.
Les dejare una parte de mi código:

```
<?php

$path="../mimusica"; //El directorio local donde almacena los archivos
$directorio= dir($path);

while ($archivo = $directorio->read();)
{

     $replace_mp3 = str_replace(".mp3","",$archivo);
     echo shuffle($replace_mp3)."<br>";

}
$directorio->close();

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estas ordenando unicamente un archivo cada vez. Tienes que almacenar los ficheros en un array y luego ordenar ese array.

```
<?php

$path="../mimusica"; //El directorio local donde almacena los archivos
$directorio= dir($path);
$arrayFiles = array();

while ($archivo = $directorio->read();)
{

     $replace_mp3 = str_replace(".mp3","",$archivo);
     $arrayFiles[] = $replace_mp3;

}
$directorio->close();

shuffle($arrayFiles);

foreach($arrayFiles as $valor){
      echo $valor."<br/>";
}

?>
```